# Jquery Textarea Not Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea that outputs HTML code. I am having difficulty getting my jsfiddle to work on my project.

It works perfectly in the JSfiddle but when I use it on my page it keeps outputting the original textarea value and not the updated one.

Should I be using a keypress to make it work or might there be a conflict with other JS code that I have?

http://jsfiddle.net/YPLeB/7/

I am using the same code on my page, but no luck.

```
<div id="update">
<textarea id="example">I cannot get the alert to show the new value</textarea>
<button id="btn">update</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {

alert($('#example').val());

});
```

Comment: are you binding the click event before the element exists?

Comment: Do you have duplicate ids? @jbabey seems like his binding is fine since it alerts on click of button.

Comment: No, I am new to jquery. I have not used binding before.

Comment: @SamitPatel It seems to be working fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/rTr7L/ Is this exactly what you are doing in your original code as well?

Comment: Nope, no duplicate IDs.

Comment: It works great on JSfiddle but on my page it alerts me with what was in the textarea on page load, not the updated value.

Comment: Do you get an error in your browsers console?

Comment: Nope, no errors in the console

Comment: @SamitPatel Just do one try  with this `alert(document.getElementById('example').value);`

Comment: Just tried that but still outputs original textarea

Comment: @SamitPatel I think better do a search on `example` as id if it is present in multiple places just to cross verify. This has to work otherwise. Reduce your original page to only this much html content and try as well..

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the issue was. I was using nicEdit text editor that was not playing well with textareas. I switched editors and now it works using .val().

Thank you all for your help!